# Meteor how to retrieve an array of questions from the mongo db and displaying just one of them within the app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

As I am new to programming and Meteor I am currently building a (simple) Quizz app using Meteor.js. I followed the discover Meteor Guide book and rebuilding their example microscope project into a quiz. **I am currently struggling with retrieving the array of questions from the mongo db and displaying just one of them within the app.**

The data within my collection currently looks like this:

```
Quizzes.insert(
    {"quiztitle": "Quiz One",
        "quizquestions": ["Q1.1", "Q1.2"]
    }),
```

I am currently displaying all of them thorugh

```
<template name="quizPage">
        <h3>
            {{#each quizquestions}}
            {{> quizQuestion}}
            {{/each}}
        </h3>
```

and

```
<template name="quizQuestion">
<div class="quiz">
    <div class="quiz-content">
        {{this}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried several solutions already to getting only the first question to display:

1.Substituting the array number through a helper function with Spacebars. Although the helper worked (it returned a specific number for instance 0), and the array by itself ( 0 between brackets). Meteor does not seem to allow spacebar inserts into array brackets.

```
<template name="quizQuestion">
<div class="quiz">
    <div class="quiz-content">
        {{quizquestions.[{{questionnumber}}]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

2.aReturning a specific field through a mongodb query. for example

```
Return Quizzes.find( { quiztitle: 'Quiz One' }, { quizquestion: 1, _id:0, quiztitle: 0 });
```

Unfortunately this is only allowed on the server side. I have also tried to save the array resulting from the return into a global variable within the lib folder

```
questionArray = Quizzes.find( { quiztitle: 'Quiz One' }, { quizquestion: 1, _id:0, quiztitle: 0 } );
```

This is also the case when I try slicing the collection, which is suggested in a different post

3.As this also does not seem to work I have tried publishing a subset of the collection for use in a specific quiz. The problem I have here is that the collection seems to be published in its entirety. I publish the collection on the frontpage.js through

```
Meteor.subscribe('quizzes');
```

I have also tried subscribing within an autorun as is suggested in the documentation at http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe

```
Deps.autorun(function () {
Meteor.subscribe("quizzes")});
```

**Question: Could you help me find a way to return only the questions array and either save it to a global variable or return it through a helper. I hope you can help me out, thanks a lot**,

Meteor Beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to make sure the data is available on the client. In chrome, open up your javascript console (cmd+option+j) and paste `Quizzes.find().fetch()` and you should see your objects. Assuming that is good, continue...

To get your questions to display, you can return the specific question to a `{{#with}}` block like this:

```
{{#with question}}
  <li>{{this}}</li>
{{/with}}
```

Your question helper could look something like this...

```
Template.TEMPLATE_NAME.helpers({
 question: function(){
  var currentQuestion = Session.get('currentQuestion') || 0;
  return Quizzes.findOne({}).quizquestions[currentQuestion]
 }
});
```

Then you can increment the Session variable each time you answer or go to the next question in a Meteor event, something like this:

```
Template.TEMP_NAME.events({   
 'click .next-question': function(){
   var num = Session.get('currentQuestion') + 1;
   Session.set('currentQuestion', num);
 }
});
```

This will cause the helper to rerun and your new question will be passed back to the `{{#with}}` block.

Answer (score 0):

In the `quizPage` template, add a helper which finds a single question:

```js
Template.quizPage.firstQuestion = function() {
  return this.quizquestions[0];
}
```

Then use it:

```html
<template name="quizPage">
  <h3>
      <!-- #with is like #each, but for a single item -->
      {{#with firstQuestion}}
        {{> quizQuestion}}
      {{/with}}
  </h3>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.    {{this.quizquestions.[0]}} does indeed work and give me the first response. But how do i get to the second response (make the 0 dynamic)? I've tried doing {{this.quizquestions.[{{questionnumber]}} but meteor does not seem to allow me to insert a value into brackets.

Comment: So to be clear, for the next step I need to make a button which changes the question number so the next question gets shown.

Comment: {{this.quizquestions.[0]}} does work but the same code in a helper (as you suggested) does not. If this would work than it would be easy to make that number dynamic

Comment: In the helper, are you writing `this.quizquestions[0]` or `this.quizquestions.[0]`? The first syntax is used in helpers, and the second in templates.